# Xamarin.Android Change ImageButton when press and release, (Error with button click not working anymore)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I tried to change the image of imageButton when on press and release, it works. But the Button.Click function won't execute/trigger anymore after I implement the code, here's my code

```
    ImageButton btnNewGame;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        btnNewGame = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnNewGame);

        btnNewGame.Click += BtnNewGame_Click;

        btnNewGame.Touch += (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                btnNewGame.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Button_New_Game_Pressed);
            }
            else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                btnNewGame.SetImageResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcMenuGallery);

            }
        };

    private void BtnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(NextPage));
        StartActivity(nextActivity);
    }
```

Can someone please tell me why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that using selectors.

Create a XML file inside the Drawables directory.

**imagebutton_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_assignment_returned_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_assignment_turned_in_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_assignment_returned_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_assignment_returned_black_24dp" />
</selector>
```

In this file you select the different states of the object, in your case the `ImageButton`.

I am defining 4 different states, you can define the ones you need and with different drawables each one, for simplicity I used the same drawable for 3 states (disabled, enabled and enabled + focused) and for pressed used a second drawable.

Now go to your Layout where the ImageButton is defined and set this as the background

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnNewGame"
    android:background="@drawable/imagebutton_selector"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp" />
```

With this you are free to remove the `OnTouch` implementation on code and the `Click` event will continue working.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so very much! Can I ask what is state_enabled, state_pressed and state_focused? Thanks!